# Python youtube-dl. ERROR: No video formats found; WARNING: unable to extract player URL;

Tags: python, heroku, youtube-api, youtube-dl

Имеется программа на Python. Одна из ее функций - получение данных о видео с YouTube, с помощью библиотеки `youtube-dl`. Программа установлена на хостинг `Heroku`. С этой библиотекой на хостинге возникают проблемы.

Периодически, при работе с `youtube-dl` возникают сбои, из-за которых команда перестает выполняться и не удается получить информацию.

---

**Ошибка возникает при выполнении извлечения информации из видео:**

Это полноценный воспроизводимый пример. Если запустить его у себя на компе, то все будет ок. Запускаем на `Heroku` - сразу же летят ошибки от библиотеки. Версии при этом одинаковые, все идентично.

```
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'False', 'forcetitle': True, 'quiet': True}

def get_data(url):
    if not url.startswith('https://'):
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(f'ytsearch:{url}', download=False)
        url = 'https://youtu.be/' + info['entries'][0]['id']
        
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        
    title = info.get('title')
    id_ = info.get('id')
    URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
    return title, id_, URL
        

urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueiqUx19vxw&ab_channel=CarMusic', 'https://youtu.be/9TnyItDcFdE', 'https://youtu.be/5QCaaAyz-yA', 'https://youtu.be/0S13mP_pfEc', 'https://youtu.be/5QCaaAyz-yA', 'муха тоже вертолет', 'del shannon run away', 'смешарики', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTFyrZo8Dns&ab_channel=detras']

for i in urls:
    title, id_, url = get_data(i)
    print(f'URL: {i}\nTitle: {title}\nID: {id_}\nRaw: {url}\n\n')
```

**Периодически получаю одну и ту же ошибку:**

```
WARNING: unable to extract player URL; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

ERROR: No video formats found; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

---

**Когда запускаю локально, у себя на компе - все работает, вопросов нет.**
Эта проблема возникает только на хостинге

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась после сегодняшнего обновления `2021.4.1`